# Interesting pattern within $m^n+1\equiv0\pmod n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In recent days, I have been studying the properties of $m^n+h\equiv0\pmod n$ where $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $h\in\mathbb{Z}$, and I have noticed that for the equation $m^n+1\equiv0\pmod n$, some even numbers n have solutions and some don't.(If $n$ is odd then $m=n-1$ is a solution.) After using a program to find the even numbers that have at least $1$ solution, I found that the list of required numbers starts with $2,10,26,34,50,58,74,82,106,122,130,146,170,178,194...$, and I noticed that the numbers in the list under $1000$ can all be written as a sum of exactly $2$ coprime square numbers. How can I prove for the general case, that for an even number $n$, $n$ can be written as a sum of exactly $2$ coprime square numbers if and only if $m^n+1\equiv0\pmod n$ has at least $1$ solution?

Comment: Fermat's Little Theorem(s) will be of huge help to you: $$a^p\equiv a \pmod p$$ and $$a^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p$$ where $p$ is prime.

Comment: For $m\leq10$ and $n\leq1000$ solutions: $(m,n)$=`(2,3), (2,9), (2,27), (2,81), (2,171), (2,243), (2,513), (2,729), (3,10), (3,50), (3,250), (4,5), (4,25), (4,125), (4,205), (4,625), (5,3), (5,9), (5,21), (5,26), (5,27), (5,63), (5,81), (5,147), (5,189), (5,243), (5,338), (5,441), (5,567), (5,609), (5,729), (5,903), (6,7), (6,49), (6,203), (6,343), (7,10), (7,50), (7,250), (8,3), (8,9), (8,27), (8,57), (8,81), (8,171), (8,243), (8,513), (8,729), (9,5), (9,25), (9,82), (9,125), (9,625), (10,11), (10,121), (10,253)`.

Comment: Write $n = 2r$. If there is an $m$ with $m^n + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{n}$, then the congruence $x^2 \equiv -1 \pmod{n}$ has a solution ($x = m^r$ is one). When is $-1$ a square modulo $n$, and when can $n$ be written as the sum of two coprime squares?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice observation! Something else you might notice, which turns out to imply your observation, is that all of the odd prime factors of your numbers are $1 \bmod 4$: $\{ 5, 13, 17, 29, \dots \}$. And a final thing you might notice is that all of your numbers are themselves congruent to $2 \bmod 4$, or equivalently are even but not divisible by $4$. This turns out to be an exact characterization:

> **Proposition:** If $n$ is an even positive integer, the following are equivalent:
>
> 1. There exists an integer $m$ such that $m^n \equiv -1 \bmod n$.
> 2. There exists an integer $x$ such that $x^2 \equiv -1 \bmod n$.
> 3. $n$ is twice a product of primes congruent to $1 \bmod 4$.
> 4. There exist integers $x, y$ such that $\gcd(x, y) = 1$ and $n = x^2 + y^2$.

*Proof.* $1 \Rightarrow 2$: if $n$ is even then $m^n = (m^{n/2})^2$.

$2 \Rightarrow 3$: if $x^2 \equiv -1 \bmod n$ then $x$ is either even, in which case $n$ is odd, or odd (in which case $x^2 + 1 \equiv 2 \bmod 4$, so if $n$ is even then $n \equiv 2 \bmod 4$, meaning $2$ divides $n$ but $4$ doesn't.

Now let $p$ be an odd prime divisor of $n$. It's a classic result that there exists a solution to $x^2 \equiv -1 \bmod p$ iff $p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$ and there are several ways to prove it; one is to use the fact that the group of units $\bmod p$ is cyclic of order $p-1$ and any root of $x^2 \equiv -1 \bmod p$ has multiplicative order exactly $4$.

$3 \Rightarrow 4$: by [Fermat's two-square theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares) (which also admits several proofs) a prime can be written in the form $x^2 + y^2$ iff $p = 2$ or $p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$, and the [Brahmagupta-Fibonacci identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity)

$$(x^2 + y^2)(z^2 + w^2) = (xz - yw)^2 + (yz + xw)^2$$

(which again admits several proofs) shows that a product of numbers of the form $x^2 + y^2$ is again of the form $x^2 + y^2$. To show that we can always arrange for $\gcd(x, y) = 1$ is slightly more annoying but still doable. If the $\gcd$ isn't equal to $1$ then it's some product of primes congruent to $1 \bmod 4$ (note that $2$ can't appear) and each of these can be written as a sum of two (coprime) squares, which lets us use the BF identity again for each such prime, and then we can check that this operation reduces the gcd. There is a maybe somewhat more conceptual proof involving the [Gaussian integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer), which are hiding in the background here.

$4 \Rightarrow 3$: suppose $n = x^2 + y^2$ where $\gcd(x, y) = 1$. Then at most one of $x, y$ is even, so $x^2 + y^2 \equiv 1, 2 \bmod 4$, so if $n$ is even then it's not divisible by $4$. If $p \mid n$ then $x^2 + y^2 \equiv 0 \bmod p$, and since $\gcd(x, y) = 1$ we get that $p$ divides at most one of $x$ and $y$, from which it follows that it divides neither. Then we can divide $\bmod p$, getting

$$\left( \frac{x}{y} \right)^2 \equiv -1 \bmod p$$

so it follows as above that $p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$.

$3 \Rightarrow 1$: We're given that $n$ is twice a product of primes congruent to $1 \bmod 4$ and we want to show that there exists $m$ such that $m^n \equiv -1 \bmod n$. We'll construct a solution $\bmod p^k$ for each prime power in the prime factorization of $n$, which is enough by the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).

First it's easy to see we can construct a solution $\bmod 2$ since $-1 \equiv 1 \bmod 2$ so we can take $m \equiv 1 \bmod 2$. Now if $p^k$ is an odd prime power factor of $n$ write $n = 2 p^k q$ where $\gcd(p, q) = 1$. We want to solve

$$m^{2 p^k q} \equiv -1 \bmod p^k.$$

To do this recall that as above, since $p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$ we know that there exists a solution to $x^2 \equiv -1 \bmod p$. By [Hensel's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma) this solution lifts to a solution to $x^2 \equiv -1 \bmod p^k$. Call it $i$ (since it's a primitive $4^{th}$ root of unity). Then

$$i^{2 p^k q} \equiv (-1)^{p^k q} \equiv -1 \bmod p^k$$

since $p^k q$ is odd. So we can take $m = i$ to be our solution $\bmod p^k$. $\Box$